# Which Compute Engine quotas need to be updated to run Dataflow with 50 workers (IN_USE_ADDRESSES, CPUS, CPUS_ALL_REGIONS ..)?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, quota

We are using a private GCP account and we would like to process 30 GB of data and do NLP processing using SpaCy. We wanted to use more workers and we decided to start with a maxiumn number of worker of 80 as show below. We submited our job and we got some issue with some of the GCP standard user quotas:

```
QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded.  Limit: 8.0 in region XXX
```

[image: distribution of the workers in Dataflow]

So I decided to request some new quotas of 50 for `IN_USE_ADDRESSES` in some region (it took me few iteration to find a region who could accept this request). We submited a new jobs and we got new quotas issues:

```
QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 24.0 in region XXX

QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'CPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded.  Limit: 32.0 globally
```

[image]

My questions is if I want to use 50 workers for example in one region, which quotas do I need to changed ? The doc https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas doesn't seems to be up to date since they only said " To use 10 Compute Engine instances, you'll need 10 in-use IP addresses.". As you can see above this is not enought and other quotas need to be changed as well. Is there some doc, blog or other post where this is documented and explained ? Just for one region there are 49 Compute Engine quotas that can be changed!

Comment: Is your dataflow currently using private IP's ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I am using the default option of Dataflow and from the doc: "If not set, the default value is true and Cloud Dataflow workers use public IP addresses. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you start using Private IP's instead of Public IP addresses. This would help in you in 2 ways:-

1. You can bypass some of the IP address related quotas as they are related to Public IP addresses.
2. Reduce costs significantly by eliminating network egress costs as the VM's would not be communicating with each other over public internet. You can find more details in this excellent article [1]

To start using the private IP's please follow the instructions as mentioned here [2]

Apart from this you would need to take care of the following quota's

## CPUs

You can increase the quota for a given region by setting the `CPUs` quota under `Compute Engine` appropriately.

## Persistent Disk

By default each VM needs a storage of  250 GB therefore for 100 instances it would be around 25TB. Please check the disk size of the workers that you are using and set the `Persistent Disk` quota under `Compute Instances` appropriately.

The default disk size is 25 GB for Cloud Dataflow Shuffle batch pipelines.

## Managed Instance Groups

You would need to take that you have enough quota in the region as Dataflow needs the following quota:-

1. One Instance Group per Cloud Dataflow job
2. One Managed Instance Group per Cloud Dataflow job
3. One Instance Template per Cloud Dataflow job

Once you review these quotas you should be all set for running the job.

1 - https://medium.com/@harshithdwivedi/how-disabling-external-ips-helped-us-cut-down-over-80-of-our-cloud-dataflow-costs-259d25aebe74

2 - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks

Comment: Another reason to not use external IPs is that [even in-use IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#ipaddress) will have a (modest) cost starting on Jan 1, 2020.

Comment: Thanks. I did the migration to private IP and it was not difficult. I am updating the qutotas as you mentioned. I don't see any quotas related tp instance template for both Compute Engine and Dataflow API. Is it a quotas that I will find with another API ?

Comment: The `instance template` is a `global` quota and is part of the `Compute Engine API` quota. Also, good to know that you migrated to Private IP's, I hope that you have turned on `private access` for the subnetwork and your CIDR block has enough addresses to run the job. If this answer was helpful please do accept the answer.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman, yes I could find the global quota, thanks. I still have an issue with private IP. I am reading a BigQuery table in US, using the endpoind of Dataflow in Belgium (europe-west1), having workers in Zurich (europe-west6) since it is the only place where I could get more quotas. I am writing the final results in BigQuety in US. With public IP, this is working fine. With private IP, it is failing with very little info. I only turned on private access in europe-west1 and europe-west6. Any idea ? Should I do that in US as well for the iteraction with BigQuery ?

Comment: As mentioned above have you turned on Private Access? Here is the link to setup Private Access - https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#configuring_access_to_google_services_from_internal_ips

Comment: Private access is turned on where I have the endpoints and workers of Dataflow. I added all the US regions (where I have the BigQuery tables). I am using the default network so i need to turned on the private access on each subnet. Anyway it seems I have something else missing to use private IP on my side.

Comment: Yes it would be good to open a support case so that they can take a look at what is missing and guide you appropriately. If this answer was helpful please do accept the answer.

Comment: I think I found the issue: I am using Dataflow with python. I have some python dependency and pip will try to install them from Internet. I guess VM without public IP cannot access Internet. I will try to add Cloud NAT. Let me manage to run my code and then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Oh yes...the other option is to create a docker image and use it.

Comment: So it is working with using Cloud Nat, private IP (private access) and the quotas mentionned above.

Comment: Nice, next step would be to start leveraging custom containers where the packages are pre installed