# How can I avoid "IN_USED_ADDRESSES" error when starting multiple Dataflow jobs from the same template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have created a Dataflow template which allows me to import data from CSV file in Cloud Storage into BigQuery. I use Cloud Function for Firebase to create jobs from this template at certain time everyday. This is the code in the Function (with some irrelevant parts removed).

```
const filePath = object.name?.replace(".csv", "");

      // Exit function if file changes are in temporary or staging folder
      if (
        filePath?.includes("staging") ||
        filePath?.includes("temp") ||
        filePath?.includes("templates")
      )
        return;

      const dataflow = google.dataflow("v1b3");
      const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
        scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
      });

      let request = {
        auth,
        projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
        location: "asia-east1",
        gcsPath: "gs://my_project_bucket/templates/csv_to_bq",
        requestBody: {
          jobName: `csv-to-bq-${filePath?.replace(/\//g, "-")}`,
          environment: {
            tempLocation: "gs://my_project_bucket/temp",
          },
          parameters: {
            input: `gs://my_project_bucket/${object.name}`,
            output: biqQueryOutput,
          },
        },
      };

      return dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch(request);
```

This function is triggered every time any file is written in Cloud Storage. I am working with sensors so at least I have to import 89 different data i.e. different CSV files within 15 minutes.

The whole process works fine if there are only 4 jobs working at the same time. However, when the function tried to create the fifth job, the API returned many different types of errors.

Error 1 (not exact since somehow I cannot find the error anymore):

```
Error Response: [400] The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES
```

Error 2:

```
Dataflow quota error for jobs-per-project quota. Project *** is running 25 jobs.
Please check the quota usage via GCP Console.
If it exceeds the limit, please wait for a workflow to finish or contact Google Cloud Support to request an increase in quota.
If it does not, contact Google Cloud Support.
```

Error 3:

```
Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Job template requests' and limit 'Job template requests per minute per user' of service 'dataflow.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:****'.
```

I know I can space out starting jobs to avoid Error 2 and 3. However, I don't know how to start jobs in a way that won't fill up the addresses. So, how do I avoid that? If I cannot, then what approach should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had answered this in another post here - [Which Compute Engine quotas need to be updated to run Dataflow with 50 workers (IN_USE_ADDRESSES, CPUS, CPUS_ALL_REGIONS ..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893082/which-compute-engine-quotas-need-to-be-updated-to-run-dataflow-with-50-workers).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I have tried using private IP addresses as you suggested in your answer and it worked! However, since there are these quotas in place I think it is more appropriate to use another approach instead. I will mark this as an answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GCP external IP quota issue and the best solution is not to use any public IPs for dataflow jobs as long as your pipeline resources stay within GCP networks.
To enable public IP in dataflow jobs:

1. Create or update your subnetwork to allow `Private google access`. this is fairly simple to do using the console - VPC > networks > subnetworks > tick enable private google access
2. In the parameters of your Cloud Dataflow job, specify `--usePublicIps=false` and `--network=[NETWORK]` or `--subnetwork=[SUBNETWORK]`.

Note: - For internal IP IN_USED errors just change your subnet CIDR range to accommodate more addresses like `20.0.0.0/16` will give you close to 60k internal IP address.

By this, you will never be exceeding your internal IP ranges